# jQuery individual item counters for multiple lists

Tags: jquery

I have multiple lists with specific items. I would like to display an item counter for each individual list. My example code so far is here below, but I'm looking for a shorter version. Probably with a for/each function? Any help is much appreciated!

```js
$('.content').each(function() {
  var one = $( '#one li' ).size();
  var two = $( '#two li' ).size();
  var three = $( '#three li' ).size();
  $( '.one' ).text(one);
  $( '.two' ).text(two);
  $( '.three' ).text(three);
});
```

```html
<div class="single">List 1 <span class="itemCount one">0</span>
  <ul id="one" class="content">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="single">List 2 <span class="itemCount two">0</span>
  <ul id="two" class="content">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="single">List 3 <span class="itemCount three">0</span>
  <ul id="three" class="content">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be sufficient:

```js
$('.content').each(function() {
    var $ul   = $(this);
    $ul.siblings('.itemCount').text( $ul.find('li').length );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="single">List 1 <span class="itemCount one">0</span>
  <ul id="one" class="content">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="single">List 2 <span class="itemCount two">0</span>
  <ul id="two" class="content">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="single">List 3 <span class="itemCount three">0</span>
  <ul id="three" class="content">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</div>
```